# print the longest sequence of number in number list (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of number:

```
a=[2,3,4,5,1,3,2,4,5,6,2,6,7,5,2,7,5,6,2]
```

I want the longest sequence that not contain 2, so the answer is:

```
[3,4,5,1,3]
```

How can I do this in python?
Thanks for helping me,

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 5, 2, 7, 5, 6, 2]

# get the subsequences not containing 2
subsequences = (list(it) 
                for contains_two, it in groupby(a, lambda x: x == 2)
                if not contains_two)

# find the longest one among them
print(max(subsequences, key=len))
```

prints

```
[3, 4, 5, 1, 3]
```

Comment: That's why python is great! Many complex things can be done in one or two lines.

Comment: @jammon: If you add comments. Because the above code is *almost* incomprehensible. :)

Comment: @Lennart: You're right, this version is much, much better. I was just pondering on a solution to the question and had something with `if`s and `for`s and some 5 to 10 lines in mind. Then I discovered this answer (and looked up itertools.groupby in the docs) and was once more baffled by the conciseness of a pythonic solution.

Comment: And comments now added, and the code is much more comprehensible. :)

Comment: @Lennart: I think the main reason the code is more readable is that I reformatted it and gave meaningful names to the variables.  Thanks for the comments anyway!